# Move a Character on a Terrain DirectX9

Tags: directx, directx-9

I have created a terrain using a raw file and I want a character to move on the terrain.

How do i Check for collisions with the terrain ?

Answer (score 2):

Simple way is to check sphere vs world collision. There is a lot of information about how to check sphere vs trianle collision. There is a lot in search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sphere+world+collision